# Does a reverse proxy influence stylesheet properties

Tags: css, primefaces, reverse-proxy

I have a completely non-intuitive situation:
1 Primefaces JSF application loaded directly from the application server - works fine.
Same JSF application loaded through an Apache reverse proxy, and the computed CSS is different. All the CSS files arrive un-corrupted in browser, but through the reverse proxy some elements get the default User Agent Stylesheet. 
I would not expect that a pass-through reverse-proxy influence CSS but apparently it does. 
Ideas?

Comment: The table is not getting all the styles applied. Specifically the elements inside table where the font-size is specified as em units, within the theme.css=redmond file. But again, all css files go through the pass-through proxy unaltered and it doesn't make sense. No 404s of-course.

Comment: My answer is definitely not "a description of an end user". I even know developers who don't use the dev. console to check what I checked before posting/answering the question :). Nevertheless, I said both in the initial post and in answer that there is no 404, so why mentioning it all over again? The problem when accessing the app through proxy is that for the table element it adds User Agent Stylesheet and then in the specified css file, the fonts are relative (in em unit) but since there is this default User Agent Ruleset applied the font of table elements is relative to an incorrect size.

Comment: PS. The above comments are answered to questions that apparently were deleted in the meantime.

Comment: Correct, they were mine and removed by me...

Comment: This may seem crazy but is the order of the stylesheets somehow being changed?